# By mistake I used private key with `ssh -i`

Tags: encryption, ssh, key-exchange

Days ago, by mistake I ran

```
$ ssh user@foo_hostmachine -i .ssh/id_rsa
```

instead of

```
$ ssh user@foo_hostmachine -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Do you think that my private key has been exposed to the Internet and I must change the private/public keys as soon as possible?

Comment: by mistake? precisely you need to use the private key (id_rsa in this case) for the `-i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No threats  to your keys due to that command. In fact with "-i" you select the file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.

Said that .ssh/id_rsa is the default value if you don't use the "-i", unless you generated multiple keys (check your ~/.ssh directory for files names ***identity***, ***id_dsa***, ***id_ecdsa*** or ***id_ed25519***)